# ComboBox binding to DataSource need to add default (blank or Add Here) and ability to set back

Tags: sql, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I have read many entries all over the web and cannot seem to find any good way to do the following.

I am currently binding a datasource to a `ComboBox`and filling it up when needed. The issue that I have this far is the user clicks on the `ComboBox` I load the data to it and bind it, but then the user cannot set it back to blank/default and has to leave a value in the `ComboBox`.

I know we can set the `ComboBox` to a `SelectItem = -1` on load or another event but I do not have an event related to fire this condition as the `ComboBox` is either set or not.

Here is what I was going to go with but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```vb
If Not IsDBNull(Me.OrgcustomerBindingSource.Current("parentID")) And Me.OrgcustomerBindingSource1.Count = 0 Then
    Me.OrgcustomerTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.LookupCustomer.orgcustomer)

    Dim dr As DataRow = DirectCast(Me.OrgcustomerBindingSource1.AddNew, DataRowView).Row
    dr.BeginEdit()
    'Add every column her with ID of 0?
    dr.Item("ID") = 0
    dr.Item("CompanyName") = ""
    '(...)

    Me.Validate()
    Me.OrgcustomerBindingSource1.EndEdit()
    Me.OrgcustomerTableAdapter1.Update(Me.LookupCustomer.orgcustomer)

    'Me.ParentIDComboBox.Items.Insert(0, String.Empty)
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set the `SelectedIndex` to -1 or the `SelectedItem` to `Nothing` to select no item. The user can't do that via the UI but you can do it in code, e.g. handle `KeyDown` and filter for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and set the appropriate property.

Comment: I am already a mousedown even to fill the data, are you saying keydown when the user manually clears the text from the box?

Comment: I tried the above and worked with you suggestion on the keydown event and added also the ctrl + del as mentioned